# Copy data from one OleDb database to another in Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, ado.net

i'm trying to create a data transfer utility, that transfers data from table of one OleDb database to table of another OleDb database. (could be SQL server or MySql or Access Database).

So far i have been successful in connecting to both databases using appropriate connection string. I have also read all the data from the source database into a OleDbDataReader. Below is the code for that.

```
 OleDbDataReader reader;
 string query = "SELECT * FROM " + stable.Text;   // text box with source table name

 cmd.CommandText = query;

 try
 {
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(ex, "Error");
    return;
 }
```

The part i'm stuck at is, how to write the data from the OleDbDataReader to the table in another database (assuming tables have similar columns). The source and data table will be entered by user during the run time.

I know for SqlConnection, we could use SqlBulkCopy for the purpose of copying everything without column mapping. But i could not find much information on how i could do that in OleDbConnection.

I'm fairly new to SQL and ado.net, so i'm really sorry if this is a stupidly simple question. I hope i have provided enough information about my issue, but if i have missed something or something doesn't make sense in my question, please do let me know.
Any help will very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to read each row of data that is generated from your query? I would maybe just iterate through your rows and INSERT the data into your other database. Or are you trying to avoid multiple INSERT calls?

Comment: No, multiple insert calls would be fine. I had a loop that read the multiple rows. But for purpose of simplicity i thought i'd first try to make one row work, and then add the loop after i figure out the solution. But is there a more efficient way to copying data from one OleDb database to another?

Comment: Simplest way You can use excel bulk upload your data

Comment: @AravindhanR Um, sorry i didn't really get that. Could you provide a sample code or link to a demonstration? Would be really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through each row with your reader and copy the values. You will have to specify the column names as I don't know what they are, or how many exist on your table. This should lead you in the right direction.

```
 //Connection to the database to be inserted
 OleDbCommand insertCmd = new OleDbCommand("Your connection");

 //Read each row and execute new query. The Reader was established previously in your code.
 while (reader.Read())
 {
       //Create your query. Each item in the first parenthesis is the column name in your table. 
       //Each item in the second set of parenthesis is a parameter to be specified later.  
       insertCmd.CommandText =  "INSERT INTO table_name (column1Name, column2Name, column3Name, ...) VALUES(@column1Name, @column2Name, @column2Name, ...)";

       //Add the parameter values. The values are pulled from the reader that's reading your "Read" database
       insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1Name", reader["column1Name"]);
       insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2Name", reader["column2Name"]);
       //...Other columns you may have

       //Execute Query
       insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  }
```

If the column names are different between tables, the reader (column#Name) will be the name of the desired column for the database being read. Let me know if you need further explanation of this example

Comment: Hi Tronald, this is a really helpful answer. To get it working in my scenario, I can get the column names for a specific table (say categories) using `SELECT *
FROM Northwind.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Categories'` and do what you suggested to achieve my objective. Thanks a lot. :)